# Which gui framework for python 3.2

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x

For some reasons I have to stick at Python 3.2. Unfortunately `wxPython` doesn't support python 3.

So which GUI framework should I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your requirements.  If [TkInter](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tkinter.html) does the job, it will be the least hassle since it comes with Python.  Otherwise, go for [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use GTK 3 through [PyGObject](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) ([turorial here](http://readthedocs.org/docs/python-gtk-3-tutorial/en/latest/index.html)).